# GitHub Actions completes job as success even it receives non-zero exit code

Tags: github-actions

I made my `test.bat` to be executed from GitHub Actions. The issue I have is that GitHub Actions completes job as success even it receives non-zero exit code from the `test.bat`.

Here is the YAML file for GitHub Actions.

```yml
jobs: 
  run_test:
    runs-on: [self-hosted,Windows]
    steps: 
    - run: ./test.bat
```

Here is the `test.bat` file that executes test.

```bat
REM This runs test and returns non-zero exit code when test fails.
test.exe -fail     

REM Now, assume test failed, and it retruns exit code 4.
echo %error_level%
```

Now, GitHub Actions completes the job as success even it receves non-zero exit code (which is 4).

If I remove `echo %error_level%` then GitHub Action completes the job as fail, properly.

Why?

Comment: Because the runner _doesn't_ receive the NZEC, `echo %error_level%` succeeds just fine.

Comment: I'd like to know why GitHub Actions job properly fails when "echo %error_level%" is removed from the "test.bat"

Comment: ...because in that case the runner _does_ receive the NZEC. Did you try this out locally? It's nothing to do with GHA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `echo` command succeeds sucessfully and returns an exit code of 0.

Make sure you either capture the `ERRORLEVEL`:

```
REM This runs test and returns non-zero exit code when test fails.
test.exe -fail     
set return_code=%ERRORLEVEL%
REM Now, assume test failed, and it returns exit code 4.
echo %return_code%
exit %return_code%
```

Or do an `if` statement and return your own exit code.

```
REM This runs test and returns non-zero exit code when test fails.
test.exe -fail

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    exit 1  
)
```